# How to split order in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2. I want to Split Order on the basis of no. of items. For example of there are four items in the cart then i want to create 4 order for that.

How can I achieve this??

Thanks

Comment: if you got this solution, please help me.